# Information about bivariate generating function from generating function in one of the variables.

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

We have a generating function enumerating some objects indexed by two variables of the form
$$
F(x, y) = \sum_{i \geq0,\ j \geq 0} f(i, j)\ x^iy^j
$$
which is symmetric, i.e $f(i, j) = f(j, i)$.

Let us then consider a generating function whose coefficients correspond to fixing one of the parameters and letting the other vary.
$$
G_j(x) = \sum_{i \geq 0} f(i, j)\ x^i
$$

If we know that $G_j(x)$ is a rational function for every fixed $j$, can we say anything about $F(x, y)$? For example, can we say if it is algebraic? D-finite?

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider the case where $f(i,j) = 0$ for $i \ne j$.  Then $G_j(x) = f(j,j) x^j$ is a monomial for each $j$, but $F(x,y) = \sum_i f(i,i) (x y)^i$ is an arbitrary series in powers of $xy$.

Comment: Okay, so that would prevent us from saying anything interesting about $F(x, y)$. What about if we tried to avoid that by saying that the coefficients have to be a growing function, i.e. that $f(i, j) < f(i+1, j)$. That would avoid this counterexample at least but I don't know if it would create any useful structure.